# How to port forward HTTP?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, home-networking

My router doesn't let me forward port 80. I get this error:

```
Error: The port of the remote web management is conflicting with of the virtual server.
```

I tried to change the web management port but it's still 80.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

When I try to change the web management port, it says it needs to be 80 or between 1024 and 65535. I changed it to 1024, rebooted the router and the web management port is still 80. Should I keep this port and setup HTTPS (wich has a different port) on my server?

Comment: Yup, go with https, you should have it enabled anyway...

Comment: Ok, thank you :)